# from byteArray to bigInteger

Tags: java, integer

how to convert a byteArray to bigInteger? it's important to say than my bytearray is not the ordinay byte[].. its a class in my project.
basically  i have an array of 256 bytes and i need to represent it as BigInteger in order to perform a calculation .

the code looks like this:

//this is how i get my information in byteArray

```
  ByteArray modulus = (ByteArray)inParamsList.getParameterType("modulus");
```

//this is the line that i get an exception for. it happens because the "toString" doesn't  actully converts it to string

```
  BigInteger modulusInBig = new BigInteger(modulus.toString());
```

i would be very happy to get some answers! i lookes all over the internet already...

Comment: did you check what does `modulus.toString()` produce?

Comment: Can we see the `ByteArray` class?

Comment: How should the bytes in the array be interpreted for conversion to a number?

Comment: @MattBall that is already defined by the constuctors of `BigInteger`.

Comment: @weston not necessarily. It depends on how the OP is currently representing the number in a byte array. There is more than one way to interpret a sequence of bits.

Comment: @MattBall My point is that `BigInteger` constructors define their inputs. All use use big-endian. OP must conform to that contract.

Comment: modulus.toString() produces ".....BasicType$ByteArray@fffffda8" it gives the path to this class... it's no good.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `ByteArray` class to provide a `toArrayByte()` method, returning `byte[]` then:

```
BigInteger modulusInBig = new BigInteger(modulus.toArrayByte());
```

Comment: you wrote: "Modify your ByteArray class to provide a toArrayByte() method, returning byte[]"... this it exacly my problem.. i'm not sure how to do that..

Comment: Then we need to see your ByteArray class. Lots of people have asked for that.